# Reduce the rank of a one one tensor of Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow tensor [[1]], how can I change this tensor to [1] which is just a number?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: [1] is not a number, it's a list (or 1D tensor) with one element.

Comment: I need to do  tf.matmul(A,wt1)) in my code, where A is something like [[1,2,3]] and wt = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([filter_size, 1], mean = 0.0, stddev = 1.0, dtype = tf.float64)). I want to store the output of matmul (something like [[1]]) but I do not know how. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I create a dummy 2D tensor and convert it to the scalar you are looking for. Note that your could run this inside a session, `tf.Session().run(tensor)` instead of the following `InteractiveSession`.

One thing to note here is that any returned tensor of `Session.run` or `eval` is a numpy array. If the returned array is multi dimensional, you could call [np.ravel()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to make it 1D and take the 1st element to make it a scalar.

```py
>>> sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
>>> t=[[10]]
>>> tensor=tf.convert_to_tensor(t)
>>> tensor.eval().ravel()[0]
10
```